# Python - passlib

Tags: python, linux, sha512, passlib

i have a problem parsing a string from a file to **passlib.hash.sha512_crypt.encrypt()**

My Code is this:

```
from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt

h = input("sha512: ")
s = input("salt: ")
d = input("dictionary: ")

dictionary = open(d, "r")

for l in dictionary:
    for i in range(1000,7000):
        t = sha512_crypt.encrypt( str(l), salt=s, rounds=i)
        print (t)
        t = t.replace("rounds=" + str(i) + "$", "")
        print("[DEBUG] SEARCHING " + str(i) + " USING " + l),
        if (t == h):
           print("FOUND AT: " + str(i) + "\nCODE IS: " + l)
           break
else:
    print("NO CODE FOUND")
```

in the file i have this:

```
password
123456789
987654321
```

i know that the default rounds for linux password for example is 5000 but in my script, when he try to encrypt the word **password** with the salt **saltsalt** he output

```
$6$saltsalt$YslT1fZBE1gwV0EkEo6UdHwwyL8M/EiBeNfZyr7TZcKxAUd0QkMaP8jmfarPGYVaNUy6haNbxsh6RKsm6dzP81
```

but when i run it from python shell i got

```
>>> from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt
>>> sha512_crypt.encrypt("password", salt="saltsalt", rounds=5000)
'$6$saltsalt$qFmFH.bQmmtXzyBY0s9v7Oicd2z4XSIecDzlB5KiA2/jctKu9YterLp8wwnSq.qc.eoxqOmSuNp2xS0ktL3nh/'
```

Why they doesn't match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first hash you posted (`"...$YslT1..."`) is actually the hash of `"password\n"`, not `"password"`, because iterating over a file handle (`l`) returns lines which include any linefeed characters.  A cheap fix would be to do `l = l.rstrip()`.